# SyntaxError: Unexpected token when compiling ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have been stuck on this error for a while and cannot figure out why I am getting this error.

In my main server file I have set the view engine to ejs :

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs")
```

Now, when I am rendering a file from **Routes**

```
router.get("/", async function (req, res) {
    res.render("main")
}
```

**main.ejs**

```
<h1>Hello :)</h1>
```

It works fine. But if I try to include partials:

```
<% include ./partials/header %> 

<h1>Hello :)</h1>

<% include ./partials/footer %>
```

I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in C:\Users\Dacvid\Desktop\Comp Web\views\main.ejs while compiling ejs
```

My directory structure is shown below:

[image: Directory structure image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using the old syntax of ejs.
Try replacing

```
<% include ./partials/header %>
```

by

```
<%- include("./partials/header") %>
```